# If $G$ is not a forest, $g(G) \leq 2\cdot \operatorname{diam}(G) + 1$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I'm struggling to prove the following elementary fact about graphs:

> If $G$ is a graph which is not a forest, $g(G) \leq 2\cdot \operatorname{diam}(G) + 1$.

I've already tried induction on the size of the graph, and looking for a contradiction taking a minimal cycle, with no luck. Any hints?

Comment: What is $g(G)$?

Comment: The *girth* of a graph $G$, defined as the minimal length of a cycle.

Comment: Should not it be connected for $diam(G) \neq \infty$?

Comment: @dEmigOd I suppose the inequality holds even in the case $\text{diag}(G) = \infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the smallest cycle in $G$. If it has length $k$, then there exist two vertices on this cycle such that the shortest path *in this cycle* between them has length $\ge \lfloor k/2 \rfloor \ge \frac{k-1}{2}$.
Now use minimality of this cycle to show that in the full graph $G$, there can be no path between these two vertices of length $< \frac{k-1}{2}$.